# index.html served by django cant locate socket.io server

Tags: javascript, python, django, node.js, sockets

I'm trying to add realtime feature to a page served by django by using node.js and socket.io

the below is my chat.js file

```
var http = require('http')
var server = http.createServer().listen(8002)
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
var redis = require('redis')
```

the portion of index.html looking to connect to the socket server

```
<script src="http://localhost:8002/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Node looks to be correctly starting the server when I use `node chat.js` , but when i start the django server , I get the below error in my console.

```
Not Found: /socket.io/
[04/Dec/2015 14:15:50] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1449238550847-26 HTTP/1.1" 404 2154
```

going to the url manually seems to show the js file as well.

Where am i going wrong?

THanks,
KJ

Comment: Can you get it from a browser? http://localhost:8002/socket.io/socket.io.js

Comment: It looks like your client is trying to connect to the Django server instead of the Node server, which suggests that your client setup is at fault. Can you show how you create the client-side connection?

Comment: @Michelem - yes , the url opens the js file

Comment: @robertklep - by client side connection , you mean the scripts i've included on the index.html page right? there isnt much else other than ''var socket = io()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're running Node.js on a separate URL, you need to point the `socket.io` client to it explicitly:

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:8002');
```